# section head box different font-size and two arguments in a level section

Tags: sectioning, formatting, titlesec

I'm expecting the below `section` heading is different box and `section number` is different box. After `A level section` default `4 icons` need to print below (please refer screenshot).

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum,mdframed}

\definecolor{sectcolor}{cmyk}{0,1,.75,.39}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]%
 {\fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont\color{white}}
  {\llap{\colorbox{sectcolor}{\makebox[1.8em][r]{\fontsize{22}{24}\selectfont\color{white}{\thesection}}}\hspace{1em}}\makebox[2em]    {\thesection}}
  {0em}{}
  {}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title Here}
\section{A level head}
\lipsum[1-3]
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one option using some boxes and the `explicit` option for `titlesec` (adjust the settings according to your needs):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum,mdframed}

\definecolor{sectcolor}{cmyk}{0,1,.75,.39}
\definecolor{sectbgcolor}{RGB}{0,106,168}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont\color{white}\bfseries}
  {\llap{\smash{\parbox[t]{2em}{\raggedleft%
      \colorbox{sectcolor}{%
        \makebox[\dimexpr2em-2\fboxsep\relax][r]{%
          \hfill\strut\thesection
        }%
      }\\[2ex]
    \includegraphics[width=1.5em]{image-1}\\
    \includegraphics[width=1.5em]{image-2}\\
    \includegraphics[width=1.5em]{image-3}\\
    \includegraphics[width=1.5em]{image-4}\\
    }}\hspace*{0.5em}}%
  }
  {0em}
  {\colorbox{sectbgcolor}{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\strut#1}}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title Here}
\section{A level head}
\lipsum[1-3]
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Since you are using a non-standard font size, make sure that you have access to that size (I used the `lmodern` font in my example code).

Comment: It's working fine. But if `\section{Place Value}{Extending}` is having two value optional argument, how to print in the `boxes`.

Comment: @Balaji That is an independant question, not mentioned in the original post. Please open a fresh new question with this new requirement.

Comment: separate question is posted in <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213745/section-head-box-different-font-size-and-two-arguments-in-a-level-section>